# Create dynamic popover from function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on translation social network, and in the posts I need to show some stats about votes for each suggestions (similar to answers in stackoverflow), so I need to create popover whenever the user hover on the label with dynamic content.

```js
    function Popx(id)
{
    $(id).popover({//here is my problem, I want dynamic id not static
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function () {
            return $.ajax({url: 'ajax/ajaxpopoverstat.php?uid=1',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false}).responseText;
        }
    }).hover(function (e) {
        $(this).popover('toggle');
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="label label-default" style="background-color: orange; font-size: x-large" data-poload="ajax/ajaxpopoverstat.php" id="xword"  onmouseover="Popx(this.id)">Suggested Word</div>
```

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the trigger you have in your popover function I am guessing you just want the popover to react to an element, and you don't necessarily want it in a function. If I am correct then [this JSFIDDLE example should do exactly what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/frjx47gg/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.label').popover({ //here is my problem, I want dynamic id not static
      html: true,
      trigger: 'hover',
      content: function() {
        return "Skittles and ids of: " + $(this)[0].id;
      }
    }).hover(function(e) {
      $(this).popover('toggle');
    });
});
```

Also in this updated fiddle I get your popover to toggle correctly:
[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frjx47gg/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

You are selecting your html tag with id variable instead of this make use of "#" hash the jquery ID selector.

**Code**

```
    function Popx(id) {
      // make use of ID selector 
      $('#' + id).popover({
        html: true,
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function () {
            return $.ajax({url: 'ajax/ajaxpopoverstat.php?uid=1',
                dataType: 'html',
                async: false}).responseText;
        }
      }).hover(function (e) {
        $(this).popover('toggle');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Although this solved my initial problem, the popover was acting in weird way, anyway thanks for your kindness, so much :)